# Got the Phusion Passenger errors with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu-12.04, passenger

I have got the seriously problem while setup rails application with Phusion Passenger. **When I run the Webrick server on port 3000 my app runs perfectly but when attempting to access it through the virtual host I continue to get Passenger errors**. Here's the info:

### Error being thrown by Passenger

[image]
[image]

### Server Information (Under VMWare)

- Distributor ID: Ubuntu
- Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-29-generic-pae i686)
- Release:        12.04.1

### Ruby and Rails Versions

- `ruby -v` = ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [i686-linux]
- `rails -v` = Rails 3.2.8
- `rvm -v` = rvm 1.16.11 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin , Michal Papis  [https://rvm.io/]

### Ruby and Rails locations

- `which ruby` = `/home/wae-group-4/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby`
- `which rails` = `/home/wae-group-4/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/rails`
- `which rvm` = `/home/wae-group-4/.rvm/bin/rvm`
- `which passenger` = `/home/wae-group-4/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/passenger`

### Results of gem list

```
    *** LOCAL GEMS ***

    actionmailer (3.2.8)
    actionpack (3.2.8)
    activemodel (3.2.8)
    activerecord (3.2.8)
    activeresource (3.2.8)
    activesupport (3.2.8)
    arel (3.0.2)
    builder (3.1.2, 3.0.3)
    bundler (1.2.1)
    cgi_multipart_eof_fix (2.5.0)
    cocaine (0.3.1)
    coffee-rails (3.2.2)
    coffee-script (2.2.0)
    coffee-script-source (1.3.3)
    daemon_controller (1.0.0)
    daemons (1.1.9)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    execjs (1.4.0)
    fastthread (1.0.7)
    gem_plugin (0.2.3)
    hike (1.2.1)
    i18n (0.6.1)
    journey (1.0.4)
    jquery-rails (2.1.2)
    json (1.7.5)
    libv8 (3.3.10.4 x86-linux)
    mail (2.4.4)
    mime-types (1.19)
    multi_json (1.3.6)
    nokogiri (1.5.5)
    paperclip (3.0.4)
    passenger (3.0.17)
    pg (0.14.1)
    polyglot (0.3.3)
    rack (1.4.1)
    rack-cache (1.2)
    rack-ssl (1.3.2)
    rack-test (0.6.1)
    rails (3.2.8)
    railties (3.2.8)
    rake (0.9.2.2)
    rb-readline (0.4.2)
    rdoc (3.12)
    rubygems-bundler (1.0.7)
    rvm (1.11.3.5)
    sass (3.2.1)
    sass-rails (3.2.5)
    sprockets (2.1.3)
    sqlite3 (1.3.6)
    therubyracer (0.10.2)
    thor (0.16.0)
    tilt (1.3.3)
    treetop (1.4.10)
    tzinfo (0.3.33)
    uglifier (1.3.0)
```

### Results of bundle list

```
    Gems included by the bundle:
      * actionmailer (3.2.8)
      * actionpack (3.2.8)
      * activemodel (3.2.8)
      * activerecord (3.2.8)
      * activeresource (3.2.8)
      * activesupport (3.2.8)
      * arel (3.0.2)
      * builder (3.0.3)
      * bundler (1.2.1)
      * cocaine (0.3.1)
      * coffee-rails (3.2.2)
      * coffee-script (2.2.0)
      * coffee-script-source (1.3.3)
      * erubis (2.7.0)
      * execjs (1.4.0)
      * hike (1.2.1)
      * i18n (0.6.1)
      * journey (1.0.4)
      * jquery-rails (2.1.2)
      * json (1.7.5)
      * libv8 (3.3.10.4)
      * mail (2.4.4)
      * mime-types (1.19)
      * multi_json (1.3.6)
      * nokogiri (1.5.5)
      * paperclip (3.0.4)
      * pg (0.14.1)
      * polyglot (0.3.3)
      * rack (1.4.1)
      * rack-cache (1.2)
      * rack-ssl (1.3.2)
      * rack-test (0.6.1)
      * rails (3.2.8)
      * railties (3.2.8)
      * rake (0.9.2.2)
      * rb-readline (0.4.2)
      * rdoc (3.12)
      * sass (3.2.1)
      * sass-rails (3.2.5)
      * sprockets (2.1.3)
      * therubyracer (0.10.2)
      * thor (0.16.0)
      * tilt (1.3.3)
      * treetop (1.4.10)
      * tzinfo (0.3.33)
      * uglifier (1.3.0)
```

### Results of rvm info

```
      ruby-1.9.3-p194:

        system:
          uname:       "Linux web4 3.2.0-29-generic-pae #46-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 27 17:25:43 UTC 2012 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux"
          system:      "ubuntu/12.04/i386"
          bash:        "/bin/bash => GNU bash, version 4.2.24(1)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu)"
          zsh:         " => not installed"

        rvm:
          version:      "rvm 1.16.11 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]"
          updated:      "4 hours 21 minutes 40 seconds ago"

        ruby:
          interpreter:  "ruby"
          version:      "1.9.3p194"
          date:         "2012-04-20"
          platform:     "i686-linux"
          patchlevel:   "2012-04-20 revision 35410"
          full_version: "ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [i686-linux]"

        homes:
          gem:          "/home/wae-group-4/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194"
          ruby:         "/home/wae-group-4/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194"

        binaries:
          ruby:         "/home/wae-group-4/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby"
          irb:          "/home/wae-group-4/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/irb"
          gem:          "/home/wae-group-4/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/gem"
          rake:         "/home/wae-group-4/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/rake"

        environment:
          PATH:         "/home/wae-group-4/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/home/wae-group-4/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin:/home/wae-group-4/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/home/wae-group-4/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games"
          GEM_HOME:     "/home/wae-group-4/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194"
          GEM_PATH:     "/home/wae-group-4/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194:/home/wae-group-4/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global"
          MY_RUBY_HOME: "/home/wae-group-4/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194"
          IRBRC:        "/home/wae-group-4/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/.irbrc"
          RUBYOPT:      ""
          gemset:       ""
```

## Gemfile Contents

```
    source 'https://rubygems.org'

    gem 'rails', '3.2.8'

    # Bundle edge Rails instead:
    # gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

    gem 'pg'


    # Gems used only for assets and not required
    # in production environments by default.
    group :assets do
      gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
      gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

      # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
      gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

      gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
    end

    gem 'jquery-rails'

    # To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
    # gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

    # To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
    # gem 'jbuilder'

    # Use unicorn as the app server
    # gem 'unicorn'

    # Deploy with Capistrano
    # gem 'capistrano'

    # To use debugger
    # gem 'debugger'

    gem 'rb-readline'
    gem 'nokogiri'
    gem 'paperclip', '3.0.4'
    gem 'rack-test'
```

## Passenger settings in apache2.conf

```
    LoadModule passenger_module /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.17/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
    PassengerRoot /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.17
    PassengerRuby /usr/bin/ruby1.8
```

## App Config in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
          ServerName 192.41.170.115
          # !!! Be sure to point DocumentRoot to 'public'!
          DocumentRoot /home/wae-group-4/web12_04/ps2/public
          <Directory /home/wae-group-4/web12_04/ps2/public>
             # This relaxes Apache security settings.
             AllowOverride all
             # MultiViews must be turned off.
             Options -MultiViews
          </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
```

## Contents of /etc/apache2/ports.conf

```
    NameVirtualHost *:80
    Listen 80

    <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
        # If you add NameVirtualHost *:443 here, you will also have to change
        # the VirtualHost statement in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl
        # to <VirtualHost *:443>
        # Server Name Indication for SSL named virtual hosts is currently not
        # supported by MSIE on Windows XP.
        Listen 443
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
        Listen 443
    </IfModule>
```

### Results of bundle install

```
    Using rake (0.9.2.2) 
    Using i18n (0.6.1) 
    Using multi_json (1.3.6) 
    Using activesupport (3.2.8) 
    Using builder (3.0.3) 
    Using activemodel (3.2.8) 
    Using erubis (2.7.0) 
    Using journey (1.0.4) 
    Using rack (1.4.1) 
    Using rack-cache (1.2) 
    Using rack-test (0.6.1) 
    Using hike (1.2.1) 
    Using tilt (1.3.3) 
    Using sprockets (2.1.3) 
    Using actionpack (3.2.8) 
    Using mime-types (1.19) 
    Using polyglot (0.3.3) 
    Using treetop (1.4.10) 
    Using mail (2.4.4) 
    Using actionmailer (3.2.8) 
    Using arel (3.0.2) 
    Using tzinfo (0.3.33) 
    Using activerecord (3.2.8) 
    Using activeresource (3.2.8) 
    Using cocaine (0.3.1) 
    Using coffee-script-source (1.3.3) 
    Using execjs (1.4.0) 
    Using coffee-script (2.2.0) 
    Using rack-ssl (1.3.2) 
    Using json (1.7.5) 
    Using rdoc (3.12) 
    Using thor (0.16.0) 
    Using railties (3.2.8) 
    Using coffee-rails (3.2.2) 
    Using jquery-rails (2.1.2) 
    Using libv8 (3.3.10.4) 
    Using nokogiri (1.5.5) 
    Using paperclip (3.0.4) 
    Using pg (0.14.1) 
    Using bundler (1.2.1) 
    Using rails (3.2.8) 
    Using rb-readline (0.4.2) 
    Using sass (3.2.1) 
    Using sass-rails (3.2.5) 
    Using therubyracer (0.10.2) 
    Using uglifier (1.3.0) 
            Your bundle is complete! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

I have faced the problem like this for many days. Should I reinstall rails , gem and rvm ? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: most detailed question ever?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have already got solution. When I have check `which passenger` , I found there are 2 place that may cause some conflict problem. Because of the previous command there:

- `sudo gem install passenger`
- `gem install passenger`

then i do

- `sudo gem uninstall passenger`
- `gem uninstall passenger`

and do

- `gem install passenger`
- `passenger-install-apache2-module`

and I got my application back .

Comment: Similar prob, two passenger modules were fighting for control--this worked for me

Comment: This page will display if you have a simple error, like forgetting to check-in a file via .gitignore and do a capistrano deployment.  This should be able to be disabled.  It is a really bad default behavior to just show all system variables anytime an error occurs on public websites!  Passenger is bad.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `bundle install` and/or `sudo bundle install` in production?

Comment: If that doesn't work, you might want to try deleting `Gemfile.lock` and trying again. And of course, you should probably restart your server after you `bundle install`. I don't know for sure if it makes a difference but it never hurts.

Comment: Thank you for your help , It seem get better but not complete yet. After I deleted `Gemfile.lock`, did `bundle install` and `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`,Even log show `Using paperclip (3.0.4)`, I got the error message `Could not find paperclip-3.0.4 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)`

Comment: And when  I deleted Gemfile.lock, did `sudo bundle install` and `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`,Even log show `Installing paperclip (3.0.4)`, I got the error message `Gem::InstallError: paperclip requires Ruby version >= 1.9.2.
An error occurred while installing paperclip (3.0.4), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install paperclip -v '3.0.4'` succeeds before bundling.)`

Comment: What do you get for `ruby -v` in production?

Comment: Yes, that's what I was asking. I don't know now. Your paperclip issue might be worthy of a separate question, since it seems to be a separate issue. I might try `bundle install` without `sudo`, too.

Comment: I got the answer now, Because of wrong passenger installation. see my answer.